# Call a function on PHP file using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, click

I have a php file (treatment.php) which contains some functions, for example :

```
public function connexion(){ 
    $user = 'invité';  
    if($_POST){
        if(isset($_POST['user'])) {
            session_start();
            $user = $_POST['user'];
        }
    }
    echo $user;
}
```

And I want to call this function via Ajax with the following code but it doesn't work :

```
$(document).on("click", "#valider-btn", function(){
  $.ajax({
    url : 'treatment.php/Connexion',
    type : 'POST',
    data : 'user=' + $("#name").val(),
    dataType : 'html',
    success : function(donnees) {
    $("#name").val("");
    $("#formulaire").hide();
    $("#decompte").html(donnees);
    }
  });
});
```

So can someone help please ? Thanks

Comment: include another.php page into the first.php by usin AJAX and setting a div with content of another.php into first.php.  In this way the another.php code will execute after some action on first.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax doesn't work like that. When you call `treatment.php`, you have to reroute the action given a certain attribute passed in the data. Like so (I'll assume your `treatment.php` isn't a class):

`treatment.php`

```
<?php

if($_POST && isset($_POST['action'])
{
    //sanitize action
    switch($_POST['action'])
    {
        case 'connexion':
            connexion($_POST['data']);
            break;
        case 'anotheraction':
        //do something
        [...]
    }
}

function connexion($data = null){ 
    $user = 'invité';  
    if($data){
        if(isset($data['user'])) {
            session_start();
            $user = $data['user'];
        }
    }
    echo $user;
}
```

`yourjs.js`:

```
$(document).on("click", "#valider-btn", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : 'treatment.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {user: $("#name").val(), action: "connexion"},
        dataType : 'html',
        success : function(donnees){
            $("#name").val("");
            $("#formulaire").hide();
            $("#decompte").html(donnees);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but for any function we add a case value

Comment: Yes indeed. It is an old-fashioned way of dealing with Ajax. Now if you are using a framework of some sort, you need to work out how to use routes.

Comment: Thank you Julien Lachal,
And if I want to put the result into a big HTML (e.g table), what can I do ?

Comment: You can have an empty (invisible) `<table>` in your HTML, and have your success callback looping through `donnees`. This way you can easily add multiple `<tr>`'s to the `<table>`

Answer (score -1):

You misunderstood PHP with JS.

You can call `.php` file, with executing code, but not function itself.
Best is to seperate PHP with `treatment2.php`:

```
<?php
include_once "treatment.php";
connexion();
```

And call this file instead.

Function itself is declaration - when you use this in PHP file, then you can execute that from outside.

Answer (score -1):

First need to jquery library.

> calling .php file extension in your ajax code

```
$(document).on("click", "#valider-btn", function(){
        $.ajax({
            url : 'treatment.php/Connexion',
            type : 'POST',
            data : 'user=' + $("#name").val(),
            dataType : 'html',
            success : function(donnees){
                $("#name").val("");
                $("#formulaire").hide();
                $("#decompte").html(donnees);
            }
        });
    });
```